# Fitting an LSTM model works on Google Colab but not on Kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, lstm, kaggle

I want to switch from Google Colab to Kaggle to run some benchmarking of a simple multilayer LSTM model but I am getting a ValueError on Kaggle which was not present on Colab.

The model is as follows

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(500, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(4, 1))) 
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And my data shape is as follows

```
X_train.shape # (38406, 4)
X_test.shape  # (9635, 4)
y_train.shape # (38406, 40)
y_test.shape  # (9635, 40)
```

Now if I run

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=120, verbose=1)
```

on Google Colab, the execution works as expected and I achieve a good accuracy. Now I downloaded the Jupiter notebook from Colab and imported it in Kaggle. Now when running the same series of commands (the shapes remain the same) I get this error

```
Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2.
```

on all Accelerators (CPU, GPU, TPU), and I do not know what is wrong (or why is it working on Google Colab and not on Kaggle).

Comment: It sounds like the dataset might be in a different format. You want to print out your dimensions to see what you're missing.

Comment: @Pam the dataset is identical I fetch it with a requests call before I define the model and print the shapes and the results are identical.

Comment: I *feel* like I've seen this before. Usually for me, it's when I think I am supplying a list of images to a classifier, but I only actually have 1 image. What I do to fix it is create a "list" of 1 image (i.e. add an extra dimension of 1 on the end). In the case of (greyscale) images, it becomes 1 dimension height, 1 width, 1 image number. With colour images, I have height, width, channel (RGB), image number.

Comment: @Pam thanks for the reply, to make it work on Kaggle I had to indeed ad a third dimension, but I still do not understand how it works on Google Colab and not anywhere else.